# Delete session in laravel5.2 when cms pages accessed

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new in laravel framework. Can anyone tell me how to delete sessions when cms pages accessed i.e(faq,privacy policy,about us). This query runs fine for me:-

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

The problem is that when i accessed the faq page i have write this query and when i accessed the privacy policy then again i have to write this query. Can anyone tell me how i do in one function. So i have not implement this query again and again

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create One middleware named as forgetSession(you can have any name) and set the cms pages route group in app\Http\routes.php under that middleware for eg.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['forgetSession']], function () {
    Route::resource('faq', 'faqController');
    Route::resource('privacy', 'privacyController');//likewise
});
```

Now create middleware by writing below command on cmd project root

```
php artisan make:middleware forgetSession
```

So it will create the middleware in app/Http/middleware/forrgetSession
and put your code

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

So in this way all route mentioned under route group will have the code to forget session. This way definitely you can redundant the code.

Comment: $request->session()->forget('key'); 
I have to put this code in handle function or somewhere

Comment: Yes in handle function on the first line

Answer (score 0):

you can remove session at your controller 
     call this in controller  contruct method

```
$request->session()->forget('key'); //remove by  key
$request->session()->flush(); // remove all
```

Comment: Flush :- it will remove all existing sessions i.e. key
I want to delete particular session

Comment: then use forget('key')

Comment: please review my question

Comment: you dont have key that you want to remove then first get all session data